# Python was not found on sublime REPL

Tags: python, sublimetext3

whenever I run a code with python into sublime text 3 the following message appears
Python was not found;run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

***Repl Closed***

how can I fix this ?? I already have the right build system and python 3 installed and set in path .

Comment: Please try running your program using the terminal. For some reason sublime text 3's ctrl+shift+B functionality doesn't run properly for correct code. If the code gives error even on the terminal/command prompt then please post that error.